# How to add link module in Bootstrap Paragraphs?

Tags: 8, navigation, paragraphs

I experiment with the xeno_hero module and Bootstrap Paragraphs module in order to create a call to action block. I want to create an image background with a centered linked textfield.

I tried a lot of options. The option of a link is not given so I tried to add link (core module) to dependencies like this

```
dependencies:
  config:
    - field.field.paragraph.xeno_hero.xeno_background_image
    - field.field.paragraph.xeno_hero.xeno_content
    - field.field.paragraph.xeno_hero.xeno_invert
    - field.field.paragraph.xeno_hero.xeno_offset
    - field.field.paragraph.xeno_hero.xeno_overlay
    - field.field.paragraph.xeno_hero.xeno_parallax
    - paragraphs.paragraphs_type.xeno_hero
    module:
    - entity_reference_revisions
    - image
    - options
    - link
```

And copied the `link.schema.yml` file from core to custom module. So far no good.

How can I add a linked textfield?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a Simple paragraph into the Content field, you can add whatever content you want in the wysiwyg without the need for a link field modification.

Here is of the hero the Bootstrap Paragraphs demo site.

[image: Screenshot of Hero bundle on the Bootstrap Paragraphs demo site]

Comment: Hi thnx how to add the blue "download now" ?

Comment: I think it's `<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">`

Comment: Yes, Bootstrap button classes.  You can add them manually in the markup, or you can also add to the styles dropdown in Drupal 8's editor.